# Как с цифровой андроид клавиатуры ввести запятую, а не точку?

Tags: android, android-edittext, интернационализация

Оказывается, на андроиде проблемы с интернационализацией. Вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь захардкожена точка и коммент, что требуется интернационализировать. Но это ещё ладно, по идее решается строчкой `setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(".,0123456789"));`. Проблема больше в другом. В том, как ввести запятую вместо точки при inputType "number" или "decimalNumber". Даже когда я нажимаю последовательность: "1,2.3" в редакторе отображается только "12.3", а при выходе из него "1,2.3".

Если inputType сделать "text", то да, я могу вводить только все из ".,0123456789", но отображается полная клавиатура с буквами.

Для ввода десятичных дробей в русской локализации я хотел бы обеспечить нормальную работу редактора EditText. Кто-нибудь знает, как с этим можно справиться.

Comment: отнаследоваться от этого класса и выполнить таки *TODO:* самостоятельно?

Comment: делал. Даже если там просто точку заменить на запятую, то ничего не меняется. При вводе (когда редактор на весь экран) "1.2.3,4" я вижу "1.234", а при выходе из редактора в поле я вижу "1.2.34,0"

Answer (score 1):

У Java нет проблем с интернационализацией:

```
DecimalFormat format=DecimalFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char separator=symbols.getDecimalSeparator(); //символ десятичного разделителя
```

Теперь это полученный `separator` вставляйте в свой массив разрешенных символов и все.